# Does Qiskit transpiler execute multiple circuits in parallel?

Tags: qiskit, programming, transpile

I have something to ask about Qiskit's transpiler.
Before that, please check this document.

```
qiskit.compiler.transpile
https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.compiler.transpile.html
```

In here, transpile function can get input as multiple quantum circuit as list and can transpile them in parallel.

I want to know how they can do in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your local environment and local configuration. By default if you're running on Linux with Python < 3.9 or macOS with Python < 3.8 then passing mutiple circuit's to `transpile()` will run in multiple process locally. This is done using Python's [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) to launch parallel processes and call transpile on each circuit in the input list in the process pool. The code for how Qiskit does this is in: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/0.18.2/qiskit/tools/parallel.py (the `parallel_map()` function is what `transpile()` uses under the covers when you pass in >1 circuit).

Also, the defaults are adjustable so if you run on windows or with a newer python version you can still run in parallel but it's not enabled by default because there were some issues found using python's `multiprocessing` module in those environments. You can refer to https://qiskit.org/documentation/configuration.html on how to set the options controlling parallelism.

Comment: Really thank you for answering my question. I want to know one more thing. My experiment environment is window, not linux. So, I want to know how I can change the number of workers (Worker's in Pool) while I'm doing parallelism.

Comment: You can refer to the configuration documentation I linked before: https://qiskit.org/documentation/locale/ko_KR/configuration.html but tl;dr if you set the environment variable: `QISKIT_PARALLEL=True` (to enable parallelism on windows) and `QISKIT_NUM_PROCS=n` where `n` is the number of processes you want to run in. You can also set these options in a user config file too.

It's worth noting that on windows you need to run your script that is executed in parallel inside `if __name == "__main__:` see: https://qiskit.org/documentation/release_notes.html#release-notes-0-17-0-known-issues

Comment: Would you tell me how to find out 'QISKIT_NUM_PROCS = n' ? I couldn't find out it.